# Lifespan of smart pointer objects declared and initialized inside WndProc message (WM_CREATE)

Tags: c++, winapi, callback

If I declare and initialize object within main window callback function like so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc
(
      HWND hWnd // handle to window of this process
    , UINT msg // message constant
    , WPARAM wParam // holder of message parameters
    , LPARAM lParam // holder of message parameters
)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Will the object `foo` stay initialized after the `break` of `WM_CREATE` message? And if not, where is the **best** place to declare it so that it's scope is not limited by the `case` scope?

The `foo` object is creating controls in the main window by the way so I think the requirement is to let it live till the end of runtime.

I suspect it will not survive. I am thinking about declaring those as global variable (but I don't like that option for obvious reasons) or as static objects within the callback function (but outside the `switch`). But there might be better options I don't see, so I am seeking your advice.

Thank you for help!

Comment: you need create instance of *Foo* before create windows and assosiate it with *hwnd* via `SetWindowLongPtrW`. free on `WM_NCDESTROY`

Comment: @RbMm this is also very elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workup of RbMm's suggestion, which I use myself in my own code.  A smart pointer has little to offer here, so there's really not much point in using one.  Please note that I have used C-style casts for brevity, but you can use `reinterpret_cast` if you prefer.

```
class MyWindowData { ... };

MyWindowData *window_data = new MyWindowData;
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow (... ... ..., (LPARAM) window_data);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCCREATE:
            CREATESTRUCT *cs = (CREATESTRUCT *) lParam;
            SetWindowLongPtr (hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, cs->lpCreateParams);
            break;

        case NC_DESTROY:
            MyWindowData *window_data = (MyWindowData *) GetWindowLongPtr (hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
            SetWindowLongPtr (hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 0);
            delete window_data;
            break;
    }

    // return something here;
}
```

You can then do:

```
MyWindowData *window_data = (MyWindowData *) GetWindowLongPtr (hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
```

to retrieve `MyWindowData` any time you need it, but check for zero being returned in case `WM_NCCREATE` is not the first message received by your `WNDPROC` as per the comments.

Comment: Thank you both, I will go with this solution (using SetWindowLongPtr) as it provides the cleanest handling.

Comment: @RbMm Sorry, it's a while since I wrote that code!  Edited.

Comment: *"to retrieve `MyWindowData` any time you need it"* - That assumes that `WM_NCCREATE` is the first message a window's window procedure processes. This is provably wrong. You can either adjust the statement, or fix the code. An implementation that associates instance data with a window object in a CBT hook is tolerant to changes in message ordering.

Comment: @IInspectable - instead use CBT hook, possible say assign pointer to object to TLS variable ( `TlsSetValue(g_i, window_data)`) and inside first callback - get window_data back `window_data = TlsGetValue(g_i)`. so not need any CBT hook set

Comment: @IInspectable What message(s) can arrive before `WM_NCCREATE`?

Comment: @PaulSanders - `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, the `WM_NCCREATE` really not first message can be

Comment: `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` is one, that you will observe today. I don't know which messages you will observe tomorrow.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, despite this is very not logical send messages before `WM_NCCREATE`. that `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` send before `WM_NCCREATE` faster is windows design bug. and can be sure enough that will be no new messages send before `WM_NCCREATE`. but anyway - yes, `WM_NCCREATE` not first message. but only use *CBT* hook (only because you view this in mfc) not need at all. store pointer to window class object (mfc use `pThreadState->m_pWndInit` for this) is enough. so for what CBT here ?

Comment: @rbm *"inside first callback"* - A consequence of this is, that you now need to check whether the instance data is initialized, *for every single message*, for the entire lifetime of the window. Setting up a CBT hook allows you to attach instance data to an `HWND` before the first message is sent to its window procedure. Once `CreateWindow` returns, you can immediately remove the local CBT hook again.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, not need. exist much more elegant solution. look in *atlwin.h* for `StartWindowProc` idea. we register it for wndclass - so it first called, and then we swith to another windowproc. this is minimal implementation for you - https://pastebin.com/WDHmpHxD (i use name `__WindowProc` instead `StartWindowProc`) and note - code absolute safe and no any CBT

Comment: @IInspectable if ignore `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` more simply solution https://pastebin.com/HPKYH1Ed (not nice of course ignore any message), but full and 100% correct - https://pastebin.com/WDHmpHxD . CBT - not need in any case

Comment: @IInspectable - how is anti-malware here related at all ? dubious code-modifying thunks ?!

Comment: @rbm [Override Process Mitigation Options to help enforce app-related security policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/override-mitigation-options-for-app-related-security-policies).

Comment: @IInspectable - and so what ? you paste some link. how this is related ?